# Method used by method reference - recognised as not used

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, sonarqube

So, I have this List of `Class` instances. I want to convert it into a List of `Constructor`s which are declared by the classes.

I map the classes to their declared constructors and flatten it with `collect`:

```
services.stream()
    .map(Class::getDeclaredConstructors)
    .collect(ArrayList::new,
        this::collectConstructors,
        List::addAll)
```

For collecting I use a method, which needs access to the class context, which is why it is not static.

```
private void collectConstructors(List<Constructor> l, Constructor<?>[] arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    Class<?> clz = arr[0].getDeclaringClass();
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        throw new MoreThanOneConstructor(clz);
    }

    if (!Modifier.isPublic(arr[0].getModifiers())) {
        throw new NoVisibleConstructor(clz);
    }

    l.add(arr[0]);
    findDefinition(clz).setConstructor(arr[0]);
}
```

The good is, everything works fine. The bad is , both IntelliJ and SonarQube tell me, that the method `collectConstructors` is not used. The ugly, or rather funny, is, IntelliJ knows perfectly that the method is used, when I click on it and the matching counterpart is highlighted.

How does it come, that the tools tell me, that the method is not used? Missing tool support? My shitty code? What is it?

Comment: Missing tool support

Comment: There's always a bug tail when new features are added to the layer below you; I'm sure this was just a minor (and easily fixable) omission on their part.  IntelliJ is very responsive to bug reports, so you might consider reporting this to them.

Comment: I would guess that you are using sonarLint and that the issue is coming from it ? if i'm correct : which version ?

Comment: @benzonico I use the maven sonar plugin and sonarqube.com as target. The Sonar version is 6.2.1

Answer (score 1):

It had been identified as a known [issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-583) in SonarQube. And it says that they have fixed that with version 4.0. It's a problem with semantic analysis.

There's no problem in your code, just the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be statically analyzed that serivces.isEmpty() is always true, therefore stream() will be empty and no collectConstructors call will be performed?

Comment: it would have to *run that code*, but even then this is an infinitely small possibility. It's most probably the tools.